# Custom Sort two arrays by value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have two different arrays which related to each other. Each value of first array is related to other array by respective key. I want to sort both array with following two conditions.

1. Sort first array by date in ascending order.
2. If date are available multiple in first array then sort both of array by value of second array in ascending order.

I have array like below.

```
[date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2018-01-06
        [1] => 2018-01-06
        [2] => 2018-01-07
        [3] => 2018-01-08
        [4] => 2018-01-06
        [5] => 2018-01-06
        [6] => 2018-01-07
        [7] => 2018-01-08
    )

[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 501
        [1] => 500
        [2] => 504
        [3] => 504
        [4] => 505
        [5] => 502
        [6] => 502
        [7] => 503
    )
```

The relation between two array is like below.

```
        Date                ID
     2018-01-06             501 
     2018-01-06             500
     2018-01-07             504
     2018-01-08             504
     2018-01-06             505
     2018-01-06             502
     2018-01-07             502
     2018-01-08             503
```

I want return array like below.

```
[date] => Array
(
    [0] => 2018-01-06
    [1] => 2018-01-06
    [2] => 2018-01-06
    [3] => 2018-01-06
    [4] => 2018-01-07
    [5] => 2018-01-07
    [6] => 2018-01-08
    [7] => 2018-01-08
)

[id] => Array
(
    [0] => 500
    [1] => 501
    [2] => 502
    [3] => 505
    [4] => 502
    [5] => 504
    [6] => 503
    [7] => 504
)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried then.

Comment: `array_multisort($date, $id);`

Comment: Have you tried [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)? It looks like the first example in the documentation does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as easy as using [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$date = array (
    0 => '2018-01-06',
    1 => '2018-01-06',
    2 => '2018-01-07',
    3 => '2018-01-08',
    4 => '2018-01-06',
    5 => '2018-01-06',
    6 => '2018-01-07',
    7 => '2018-01-08',
);

$id = array(
    0 => 501,
    1 => 500,
    2 => 504,
    3 => 504,
    4 => 505,
    5 => 502,
    6 => 502,
    7 => 503,
);


array_multisort($date, $id);

print_r($date);
print_r($id);
```

It produces the output you expect.

It also works if the input arrays are values in a larger array (as it seems to be your case):

```
$input = array(
    'date' => array(
        0 => '2018-01-06',
        1 => '2018-01-06',
        2 => '2018-01-07',
        3 => '2018-01-08',
        4 => '2018-01-06',
        5 => '2018-01-06',
        6 => '2018-01-07',
        7 => '2018-01-08',
    ),
    'id' => array(
        0 => 501,
        1 => 500,
        2 => 504,
        3 => 504,
        4 => 505,
        5 => 502,
        6 => 502,
        7 => 503,
    ),
);

array_multisort($input['date'], $input['id']);

print_r($input);
```